# pyaudio mac python 2.7, play audio in the background (asynchronously)?

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, pyaudio

I am making a game and I want to start a sound as the animation begins, but right now, it first plays the sound and then does the animation. Is there a way to do this so that both happen together?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a game, you should probably use [pygame](http://pygame.org/), which can play sounds in the background and much more.
If that's too complicated for your use case, you can use [sounddevice.play()](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.org/#sounddevice.play), which by default plays asynchronously:

```
import sounddevice as sd
sd.play(mydata, 44100)
```